# Type Constraint in Constructor

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make a normal form game solver for game theory, and I'm trying to make it as generic as possible for good practice and for my own convenience. I would like to use the same functions to solve both zero-sum and non-zero-sum games, so I am using the following data type:

```
data Payoffs = (Num a, Eq a, Ord a) => ZS  a
             | (Num a, Eq a, Ord a) => NZS (a,a)
```

However, this is not correct syntax. Is there any way to constrain `a` so that it must satisfy those type constraints?

Comment: Did you mean to write `data Payoffs a = ...` perhaps?

Comment: Complete side comment: don't `NZS (a,a)`. Instead `NZS a a`. The extra tuple constructor isn't doing anything good for you (and is doing something bad: extra allocation and indirection).

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm using a tuple because it is supposed to be a tuple mathematically

Comment: @n.m. if I write `data Payoffs a = ...` will I still be able to compare a payoff of `Int`s with a payoff of `Fractional`s?

Comment: Mathematically, you may think of the author having added a short sentence at the start of their manuscript saying, "When I write the syntax `(x, y)` as the payoffs of a non-zero sum game, I am using this as a pretty notation whose actual meaning is `NZS x y`.". Then you may feel free to move forward with `NZS a a` instead of `NZS (a,a)`. (After all, I bet you are implicitly already imagining a similar sentence for your other constructor... or do the math definitions you are reading really include `ZS` tags all over the place...?)

Comment: @DanielWagner ok I guess I could do that, just reluctant because the ordered pair is 1 thing, like a point. In Haskell graphics libraries, are points constructed using tuples or with multiple arguments?

Comment: @Agent008 There are libraries that make each of those choices, and there are more choices besides that which you have not yet imagined. I don't really see how that's relevant, though.

Comment: If you can compare an Int with a Fractional without having any Payoff, then you can do the same when wrapped in a Payoff. Can you?

Comment: @DanielWagner I was just wondering if it is idiomatic to have these kinds of functions without using tuples, and judging by your responses I think it is!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer** (and probably not the one you need):
To make your code work as is, you need a `forall` quantifier (for which you need to enable `ExistentialQuantification`):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data Payoffs =
      forall a. (Num a, Eq a, Ord a) => ZS a
    | forall a. (Num a, Eq a, Ord a) => NZS (a,a)
```

---

If you have a type variable in the data constructor (i.e. `ZS a`), then you have two choices: either that variable has to appear in the type constructor (i.e. `data Payoffs a =`), or you need to say "*I don't care what type it is, as long as it supports these classes*" - which is achieved via the `forall` quantifier.

But this looks kinda useless to me, which suggests that you may be misunderstanding what it means. If you write the above code, every value of your `Payoffs` type will be able to wrap a value of *any* type, as long as that type supports `Num`, `Eq`, and `Ord`. One subtle consequence of this is that, if you have two values of `Payoffs` lying around, they *will not necessarily wrap the same type*. For example:

```
let x = ZS (42 :: Int)  -- wraps an Int
let y = NZS (2.71 :: Double, 3.14)  -- wraps two Doubles
```

This means that, upon unpacking them, you won't be able to, for example, add them together, because, even though they both implement `Num`, the compiler doesn't have any proof that they're actually the same type.

What I suspect you actually need is a parametrized type, like this:

```
data Payoffs a = ZS a | NZS (a, a)
```

But then, of course, you lose the constraints: anybody can go and create `ZS String` or something. You can use the GADT syntax (with the `GADTs` extension) to bring them back:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Payoffs a where
    ZS :: (Num a, Ord a, Eq a) => a -> Payoffs a
    NZS :: (Num a, Ord a, Eq a) => (a, a) -> Payoffs a
```

This notation is equivalent to `ZS a | NZS (a, a)`, except you get to define each constructor with the same syntax as any function - including constraints. A type defined like this won't allow for creating values of type `Payoffs a` unless `a` satisfies the constraints.

At the same time, if you have a value of a type like this lying around, you know what type it wraps inside. And this allows you to tell if two `Payoffs` values wrap the same type or different. And then, if you know that they're the same, you can do things with them using the supported classes, for example:

```
addPayoffs :: Payoffs a -> Payoffs a -> Payoffs a
addPayoffs (ZS a) (ZS b) = ZS (a + b)
addPayoffs (ZS a) (NZS (x,y)) = NZS (a+x, a+y)
... etc.
```

Comment: I will use GADT syntax. Is it also worth it to then make `Payoffs` an instance of `Num`, `Eq`, and `Ord`, or is this unnecessary?